# If a correct answer is deprecated, should I vote it down?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting

Based upon the following question/answers:

[Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

A correct but deprecated answer shows 10 votes.  Were it not for the comment (with currently 6+ upvotes), I would not have necessarily known the answer was deprecated, because it still works.

Using StackOverflow as I do, I like would hope that this answer would eventually "fade away", but it isn't really right to penalize a person for an answer that will be deprecated in the future.

What is the proper action:

- Vote the deprecated answer down, because it isn't relevant?
- Edit the deprecated answer, and mark it **at the top of the answer** that it is now deprecated?
- Just vote up the most correct answer, hoping that it will attract future user's attention?

When I loaded the question, the deprecated answer was on top, even though it had far fewer votes than the correct answer.  Please note, that in this case, the OP didn't accept either answer.

Comment: You could add your own perfect and correct answer and/or comment on the deprecated ones so that the posters could correct them.

Comment: @ShaunakD, I agree, but in this case, the comment was already there, as well as the perfect answer.  It just wasn't immediately obvious, until after I tried the code and (luckily) saw the comment.  Maybe I move too fast without checking, but it seemed a natural answer.

Comment: Then you should go with the third option. Well, downvoting is totally upto you. And editing the top answer doesn't seem to be good as the sorting of the posts might differ on the tab selected by the users.

Comment: Is the answer *bad*, or just *old*? Does it still apply to earlier versions, for example?

Comment: I have posted several times in meta that I think the current solutions to this are not very good and a new system should be created. I would love to be able to have only Swift 1.2 answers when I search rather than have to debug code.

Comment: Then perform an edit providing the depreciated answer and the latest answer to accommodate users who encounters the same problem who uses the previous and the latest version.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, the answer is not bad at all, just not relevant to the latest version.  So, timpone's point is relevant; maybe the tags should not be for `php`, but rather `php 5.3`, or something of the like.  The SO system could be upgraded to comprehend something like this.

Comment: In that case it would be best to comment on or edit the answer (according to your rep) to clarify the version(s) it applies to (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10166574/3001761) and add a new answer starting e.g. *"From version x.y ..."*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implement a vote-based warning system for potentially dangerous answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298905/implement-a-vote-based-warning-system-for-potentially-dangerous-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Proper action:

- Vote the deprecated answer down, because it isn't relevant?
- Edit the deprecated answer, and mark it at the top of the answer that
  it is now deprecated?
- Just vote up the most correct answer, hoping that it will attract
  future user's attention?
- **Just comment the answer that its deprecated. And if u can ,Just
  comment the new answer corresponding to the deprecated answer.**

Go for the 4th option.